# I'm using the Global Entry for the first time to book a flight. Do I use only the first 9 digits, or also the letters and the 3-digit code?

Tags: bookings, airlines, global-entry

On my Global Entry card, there's a PASSID consisting of 9 digits. Following those digits, there's "SC" and then an additional 3 digits. When I enter my PASSID, should I input only the 9 digits, or do I also need to include "SC" and the subsequent 3-digit code? I've been searching, but I haven't found an answer yet.

Answer (score 13):

Your Known Traveler Number has nine digits. The security code (SC numbers) functions similar to CVV on the back of your credit card and may be needed for activation or verification purposes, but is ignored when you enter KTN for an airline booking.

https://www.tsa.gov/travel/frequently-asked-questions/what-known-traveler-number-ktn